# Google Apps Gadget - Broken without repair in the new console

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I am trying to port our old code to the new console API. Believe me, I like the old manifest approach as it was working and I don't like changing anything which is working.

- I setup our old gadget which had some custom extractors which wasn't loading. there were some users complaining on stackoverflow. no console errors too. no network requests too in Chrome Debugger.

then, I tried with a sample project to see if the hello world gadget even works. To my despair, it doesn't

```
google.com:HelloWorld
Gadget url: https://googledrive.com/host/0B0JNj_IM2wiPb1NaX1B0S29MQlE/helloworldgadget.xml
Parameter name: hello
Parameter value: *
Scopes:
Mail - Subject Line
Mail - Message Body
```

I enabled COB extension, I tried this as an admin. For the life of me, it doesn't load. Tried with other extractors.. Just doesn't work. Logged off, tried with nogadgetcache and other users. I have experience programming old gadgets; I know how to reload from using the old gadet. But here I am out of luck.

Can someone from Google lend me a hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter value for empty filter needs to have a dot in front of it, I don't know if it is a typing mistake in your question, but it should be 'Parameter value: .*'

A few of the things that I did when I had the same problems with a gadget not showing up:

- the Parameter names in the COB extension need to be exactly as Google specifies them in the documentation. For example, for google.com:RecipientToEmailExtractor, the parameter name needs to be 'recipient_to_email', otherwise the filter will not return anything.
- when testing make sure all the scopes from the app are given permissions from the Admin console. If your app is installed, and you are just testing various variants of the COB extension parameters, you need to always make sure to re-grant permissions for new scopes in the Google admin console.
- if all else fails, login with another account in another browser and see if the gadget appears then, when doing a lot of testing I noticed that cache is a problem even if you put '&nogadgetcache=1' in the URL.

Hope this helps.